# Meaning of "But no Source never made me not buy an album when they say it was wack"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, double-negation, african-american-vernacular-english

I cannot get the real meaning of [this AAVE](https://genius.com/131345) sentence from rapper Kon Artis, a song lyric transcribed at Genius:

> But no Source never made me not buy an album when they say it was wack

*Source* is the name of a magazine.

Comment: I edited your question to provide the actual quote and attribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's confusing because there are so many negatives that don't belong in the sentence and some slang, so it takes some parsing to correct them to standard English. I must admit I also did a double- and triple-take on this before I figured out the meaning.

> No Source never made me not buy an album when they say it was wack

First off, let's start by identifying the phrase pattern that is:

> No X ever made me do Y.

At the base, it means what it reads. No such X ever made the OP perform an action Y.

Now, apply a double-negative (which is deliberately wrong) to this:

> No X never made me do Y.

So what is Y?

> ...not buy an album when they say it was wack.

So, we know X to be the magazine *Source*. We know Y to be the negative non-action that is "not buy an album when (Source) said it was "wack"."

So, OP is trying to say that Source magazine, despite a bad review of an album, never made OP not buy it. To phrase it a different way:

> Even if Source says the album is bad, I'd still buy it.

Comment: I think a comma is missing before 'No' ('No, Source never...'). The double-negative isn't no/never, it's never/not. The 'No' is simply introductory, as if the writer of the sentence is answering a question.

Comment: @Gwendolyn - missing *after* 'No'

Comment: This is a most confusing answer!

Comment: I highly doubt that it is introductory, as that's not its usage in Ebonics, and the source content is lyrics from a rap in a song.

Comment: @MartinF Oops! Yes, that's what I meant.  Comma after 'No'. :) 
I'd also say the lyric is even more confusing than the answer!

Comment: @psosuna The lyric has since been edited since my first comment, but I'm not sure it changes my thoughts. I've read a lot of incorrect lyrics on Genius, spelling, grammar, or otherwise. Nevertheless, is this a "triple-negatives"? Is that a thing? Ha. No/not/never.

Comment: @Gwendolyn No, but you seem to be under the misconception that this is standard English we are discussing, when it isn't. This falls under Ebonics. There are differences in expressing negatives between the two.